# Issue with accepting user inputs in Jython script

Tags: python, input, jython-2.5

I'm newbie in jython please find my learing environment details

JYTHON : Jython 2.5.4rc1 (2.5:723492dbab02, Feb 8 2013, 09:50:55)
JAVA : [Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (Oracle Corporation)] on java1.7.0_01
PYTHON : Python 3.3
IDE : PyDev on Juno Service Release 1
OS : Windows 7, 64 bit

While trying to run a program which I took from the internet. 
This program expects some inputs from the end user (C, M or X) something like :

`enterPlayer = input("Would you like to create a team or manage an existing team?\n (Enter 'C' for create, 'M' for manage, 'X' to exit) ")`
 
This workks fine if run this program with python (using pydev). But if run this as a jython, the program breaks down and if I print the enterPlayer [`print (enterPlayer.upper())`] variable (the varable which stores the input from the user) the value is shown as `"__PYCLASSPATH__/"`.

i.e the program works as intended if i choose python otherwise (jython) it breaks.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input` : `raw_input` = `Python 3.x` : `Python 2.x`

If you want to run your program both in Python 3.x and Python 2.x (Jython 2.x), Put following lines at the beginning of your program.

```
import sys
if sys.hexversion < 0x3000000:
    input = raw_input
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I tried the same way as you suggested. Its works fine now. Thanks. But my editor (pydev) gives me an error saying that raw_input is an undefined variable. Is there a way to correct this issue?

Comment: replace `raw_input` to `eval('raw_input')`. This will make pydev happy, but not good. Maybe there is some editor setting to suppress variable check... (guess)

Comment: Thanks again, it works (with your warning). Aslo tried with the option Window -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Editor -> Code Analysis -> Undefined -> Undefined Variable From Import -> Ignore but this does not help me to remove the error marker. Any ways will try to find it out.